# Adding subview with constraints takes 1 second to display

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a MKAnnotation with a calloutAccessoryControl. When pressed, I display a UIView:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {
NSDate *start = [NSDate date];

DLog(@"fired");
DLog(@"thread: %@", [NSThread currentThread]);

EntityPoint *entityPoint = (EntityPoint *)view.annotation;

EntityFormView *entityFormView = entityPoint.entityFormView;

DLog(@"addind subview: %f", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:start]);

[self.view addSubview:entityFormView.screenView];

DLog(@"addind constraints: %f", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:start]);

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[screenView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"screenView": entityFormView.screenView}]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[screenView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"screenView": entityFormView.screenView}]];

DLog(@"finished , doing animation: %f", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:start]);

[UIView animateWithDuration:.1
                 animations:^{
                     entityFormView.screenView.alpha = 1;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     DLog(@"completely finished: %f", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:start]);
                 }];
```

}

The first time I run this code, it happens in ~.2 seconds. I close it then reopen it and it will take ~1.2 secionds:

```
 DEBUG | -[MapViewController mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:] | fired
 DEBUG | -[MapViewController mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:] | thread: <NSThread: 0x1d548bc0>{name = (null), num = 1}
 DEBUG | -[MapViewController mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:] | addind subview: 0.005463
 DEBUG | -[MapViewController mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:] | addind constraints: 0.047544
 DEBUG | -[MapViewController mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:] | finished , doing animation: 0.049323
 DEBUG | __74-[MapViewController mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:]_block_invoke1001 | completely finished: 0.199709

 DEBUG | -[MapViewController mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:] | fired
 DEBUG | -[MapViewController mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:] | thread: <NSThread: 0x1d548bc0>{name = (null), num = 1}
 DEBUG | -[MapViewController mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:] | addind subview: 0.006285
 DEBUG | -[MapViewController mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:] | addind constraints: 1.069605
 DEBUG | -[MapViewController mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:] | finished , doing animation: 1.082836
 DEBUG | __74-[MapViewController mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:]_block_invoke1001 | completely finished: 1.194132
```

When I remove the UIView:

```
-(void)removeForm {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.1
                     animations:^{
                         self.screenView.alpha = 0;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [self.screenView removeFromSuperview];
                     }];
}
```

Why is it adding the subView after the first time taking so long? /baffled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around with it and while solving another issue  I was having, I also solved this issue.

The form view was a subclassed `UIScrollView` and to close the view, you need to scroll down to click the save button. This would cause the `contentOffset` to be set to 145. After it closes, I set the `contentOffset` back to 0. This solved my slow display issue.

My best guess is that the `UIScrollView` was animating to the offset while the alpha was still 0. Once it animated to the offset, it would animate the alpha to 1.

Answer (score 0):

It sort of looks like the first time it's run, the alpha animation isn't happening, which is pretty strange. Your completion `completely finished` log should be timestamped about 1s after the `doing animation` log. I would say to start investigating there, since it's the first thing in the sequence of events that looks incorrect. Perhaps when it's first run, the alpha of the UIView is already 1.0, so it doesn't fade in?